# If the product of two elements from components of finite group is involution, then are the factors also involutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and denote by $E(G)$ the subgroup generated by all [components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(group_theory)) of $G$. Suppose $E$ is a component and choose $L \le E(G)$ such that $E(G) = E\cdot L$. Let $y \in E(G)$ be nontrivial and $y \notin E$, and choose $y = y_1a$ with $y_1 \in E$ and $a \in L$.

Suppose $|C_E(y)| \le 2$, hence $y^2 = 1$. Now suppose $y_1 \ne 1$.

> Does it follow that $y_1$ is an involution?

As $a$ and $y_1$ commute, we have $|y|$ divides $\operatorname{lcm}(|y_1|, |a|)$, as could be [read here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/the-order-of-a-product-of-commuting-group-elements-divides-the-least-common-multiple-of-the-orders-of-the-elements/), that is the only think I know to deduce something about the order of $y_1$, so how could we deduce that $y_1^2 = 1$?

This is part of an argument which aims to derive a contradiction. So as a whole this situation is not possible. The rest of the argument goes like this: If $x \in E$ commutes with $y_1$, then as it also commutes with $a$ we have $C_E(y_1) \le C_E(y)$, and conversely if $x \in E$ commutes with $y$, as $y_1 = ya^{-1}$ we have similarly $C_E(y) \le C_E(y_1)$. So as $y_1 \ne y$ by the assumption $y \notin E$ we would have $\{1,y,y_1,yy_1\} \subseteq C_E(y)$, contradicting $|C_E(y)| \le 2$. This gives $y_1 = 1$ and $y = a \in L$, and hence $E \le C_E(y)$, which is similarly not possible as components could not have order $2$.

Comment: $|C_E(y)| \le 2$ implies that $E$ has twice odd order, and hence it cannot be perfect, contradiction.

Comment: @DerekHolt Because $C_E(y) \le \langle y \rangle = \{1,y\}$ implies that $E$ is a Frobenius group with complement $\langle y \rangle$, and this is a Hall subgroup? Thanks for giving an earlier contradiction; but is it possible to proceed along the original argument, i.e. deducing that $y_1$ is an involution? Because if possible I want to understand that reasoning too...

Comment: Oh just saw that $C_G(h) \le H$ for all $h \in H^{\#}$ and some subgroup $H \le G$ is not sufficient for being a Frobenius group, we further need that $G$ is a semidirect product of $H$ and some normal subgroup. Okay, then I have to think about your argument further; but anyway could we deduce that $y_1$ is an involution.

Comment: I have no idea. Once you make contradictory assumptions, you can deduce anything.

Comment: Yes, okay thank you! May I add that this is from the same paper where the following similar argument/conclusion was made: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654787/if-e-in-e-where-e-is-a-component-of-a-permutation-group-then-e-has-order